# How to find the number of lines in a text file given input in a program

Tags: c

We have to create 2 programs `sortwords.c` and `print_anagrams.c`

We are then supposed to type the command (to obtain the output):

```
./sortwords < wordfile.txt | sort | ./print_anagrams > anagrams.txt
```

In the `sortwords.c` program, I'm using `gets()` function, but I don't know how many times I should loop it. I have a similar problem with `print_anagrams.c`... I don't know how many input lines, so I don't know how many times should I call `gets()`.

Any suggestions for how I can get the number of lines within the program?

Comment: You read until `EOF` — `gets` will return `NULL`. But be careful with `gets`, as you might overflow your buffer.